# var_dump(str_replace) works but var_dump($var) doesn't

Tags: php, str-replace

So I have this:

```
print_r($test);
```

it returns `'E14'`

Then if I do this:

```
    var_dump(str_replace("E","",$test));
```

it returns `string(4) "'14'"`

Everything nice until:

```
str_replace("E","",$test);
var_dump($test);
```

that returns: `string(5) "'E14'"`

How am I supposed to make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: str_replace returns a new value, it doesn't change the old one

Comment: @GordonM thats all I needed to know , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace("E","",$test);`
is not assigned to `$test`

use:

```
$test = str_replace("E","",$test);
var_dump($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
$newStr = str_replace("E","",$test);
var_dump($newStr);
```